# Integral coordinate change

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I'm trying to compute

$$\int_0^n\int_0^n\int_0^n\frac{\sin(x-y)\sin(y-z)\sin(x-z)}{(x-y)(x-z)(y-z)}\,dx \,dy \,dz$$

I want to make new coordinates as $a=x-y$, $b= y-z$ (so $x-z=a+b$) and $c=z$. I'm a bit confused about the limits of the integral, can anyone help?